# BeautifulSoup: Why doesn't it find all iframes?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to BeautifulSoup, and I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't work as expected.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("https://www.globes.co.il/news/article.aspx?did=1001285710")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), features="html.parser")
print(bsObj.find_all('iframe'))
```

I get a list of only 2 iframes. 
However, when I open this page with a browser and type:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")
```

in dev-tools I get a list of 14 elements.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because that site dynamically adds more iframes once the page is loaded. Additionally, iframe content is dynamically loaded by a browser, and won't be downloaded via urlopen either. You may need to use Selenium to allow JavaScript to load the additional iframes, and then may need to search for the iframe and download the content via the src url.